# ZGC not supported with OpenJDK 11 and macOS?

Tags: java, gradle, garbage-collection, java-11, zgc

I'm trying to run a spring boot application with ZGC Garbage Collector, with following JVM options passed in `build.gradle`:

```
bootRun {
    jvmArgs = ["-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions", "-XX:+UseZGC", "-Xlog:gc*"]
}
```

While running an app (`gradle bootRun`) I'm getting following error:

```
> Task :bootRun FAILED
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Option -XX:+UseZGC not supported
```

java -version:

```
openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.6+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.6+10, mixed mode)
```

I'm running 10.15.2 (19C57) version of macOS (Catalina) if that helps. Is it only macOS issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find the details over the supported platforms under the [ZGC wiki](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/zgc/Main#Main-SupportedPlatforms).

[image]

So as it seems like, you would have to move to JDK-14 to be able to use it with macOS.

Comment: Can't believe I've missed that... Thanks!